# Unable to fetch data from on premise system using s4sdk

Tags: s4sdk

I followed the tutorial:  https://open.sap.com/courses/s4h13/items/258qEhXx5kdG8b4SXMSJYp
I am able to fetch data from mocked service, but I get an empty array when I add an on premise sap system in my destination.
I am trying to read ProductMaster service (which is available in my sap system).
any guidance or link of correct blog will be much appreciated.

Application logs:-

2019-01-31T09:49:30.98+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "written_at":"2019-01-31T04:19:30.980Z","written_ts":3583833066597470,"component_id":"ae30fb63-3ddc-42e4-95c9-c190e7c5950e","component_name":"address-manager","DCComponent":"","HOST":"0ca2bbc0-3f71-4dfd-5e4e-8577","organization_name":"-","component_type":"application","space_name":"dev","SERVER":"main","component_instance":"0","organization_id":"-","correlation_id":"-","CSNComponent":"","space_id":"71c96992-bd88-41e6-ac83-bdcc94e38fc6","Application":"address-manager","container_id":"10.0.137.101","type":"log","logger":"com.sap.xs2.security.container.UserInfoTomcat","thread":"http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-1","level":"INFO","categories":[],"msg":"Parsing SAP_JWT_TRUST_ACL (value: [{\"clientid\" : \"*\", \"identityzone\" : \"*\"}])" }
   2019-01-31T09:49:30.98+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "written_at":"2019-01-31T04:19:30.980Z","written_ts":3583833067255806,"component_id":"ae30fb63-3ddc-42e4-95c9-c190e7c5950e","component_name":"address-manager","DCComponent":"","HOST":"0ca2bbc0-3f71-4dfd-5e4e-8577","organization_name":"-","component_type":"application","space_name":"dev","SERVER":"main","component_instance":"0","organization_id":"-","correlation_id":"-","CSNComponent":"","space_id":"71c96992-bd88-41e6-ac83-bdcc94e38fc6","Application":"address-manager","container_id":"10.0.137.101","type":"log","logger":"com.sap.xs2.security.container.UserInfoTomcat","thread":"http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-1","level":"INFO","categories":[],"msg":"Access token of service plan \"application\" received" }
   2019-01-31T09:49:30.98+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "written_at":"2019-01-31T04:19:30.980Z","written_ts":3583833067335285,"component_id":"ae30fb63-3ddc-42e4-95c9-c190e7c5950e","component_name":"address-manager","DCComponent":"","HOST":"0ca2bbc0-3f71-4dfd-5e4e-8577","organization_name":"-","component_type":"application","space_name":"dev","SERVER":"main","component_instance":"0","organization_id":"-","correlation_id":"-","CSNComponent":"","space_id":"71c96992-bd88-41e6-ac83-bdcc94e38fc6","Application":"address-manager","container_id":"10.0.137.101","type":"log","logger":"com.sap.xs2.security.commons.SAPVcapServicesParser","thread":"http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-1","level":"INFO","categories":[],"msg":"VCAP_SERVICES: Only one applicable binding exists, service plan hint \"application\" is not used" }
   2019-01-31T09:49:30.98+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "written_at":"2019-01-31T04:19:30.980Z","written_ts":3583833067403879,"component_id":"ae30fb63-3ddc-42e4-95c9-c190e7c5950e","component_name":"address-manager","DCComponent":"","HOST":"0ca2bbc0-3f71-4dfd-5e4e-8577","organization_name":"-","component_type":"application","space_name":"dev","SERVER":"main","component_instance":"0","organization_id":"-","correlation_id":"-","CSNComponent":"","space_id":"71c96992-bd88-41e6-ac83-bdcc94e38fc6","Application":"address-manager","container_id":"10.0.137.101","type":"log","logger":"com.sap.xs2.security.commons.SAPPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer","thread":"http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-1","level":"INFO","categories":[],"msg":"Got from VCAP_SERVICES: clientid=sb-address-manager-p1942271708trial!t9649" }
   2019-01-31T09:49:37.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "written_at":"2019-01-31T04:19:37.030Z","written_ts":3583839116771998,"component_id":"ae30fb63-3ddc-42e4-95c9-c190e7c5950e","component_name":"address-manager","DCComponent":"","HOST":"0ca2bbc0-3f71-4dfd-5e4e-8577","organization_name":"-","component_type":"application","space_name":"dev","SERVER":"main","component_instance":"0","organization_id":"-","correlation_id":"-","CSNComponent":"","space_id":"71c96992-bd88-41e6-ac83-bdcc94e38fc6","Application":"address-manager","container_id":"10.0.137.101","type":"log","logger":"com.sap.xs2.security.container.UserInfoTomcat","thread":"http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-3","level":"INFO","categories":[],"msg":"Parsing SAP_JWT_TRUST_ACL (value: [{\"clientid\" : \"*\", \"identityzone\" : \"*\"}])" }
   2019-01-31T09:49:37.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "written_at":"2019-01-31T04:19:37.030Z","written_ts":3583839117339973,"component_id":"ae30fb63-3ddc-42e4-95c9-c190e7c5950e","component_name":"address-manager","DCComponent":"","HOST":"0ca2bbc0-3f71-4dfd-5e4e-8577","organization_name":"-","component_type":"application","space_name":"dev","SERVER":"main","component_instance":"0","organization_id":"-","correlation_id":"-","CSNComponent":"","space_id":"71c96992-bd88-41e6-ac83-bdcc94e38fc6","Application":"address-manager","container_id":"10.0.137.101","type":"log","logger":"com.sap.xs2.security.container.UserInfoTomcat","thread":"http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-3","level":"INFO","categories":[],"msg":"Access token of service plan \"application\" received" }
   2019-01-31T09:49:37.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "written_at":"2019-01-31T04:19:37.030Z","written_ts":3583839117412082,"component_id":"ae30fb63-3ddc-42e4-95c9-c190e7c5950e","component_name":"address-manager","DCComponent":"","HOST":"0ca2bbc0-3f71-4dfd-5e4e-8577","organization_name":"-","component_type":"application","space_name":"dev","SERVER":"main","component_instance":"0","organization_id":"-","correlation_id":"-","CSNComponent":"","space_id":"71c96992-bd88-41e6-ac83-bdcc94e38fc6","Application":"address-manager","container_id":"10.0.137.101","type":"log","logger":"com.sap.xs2.security.commons.SAPVcapServicesParser","thread":"http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-3","level":"INFO","categories":[],"msg":"VCAP_SERVICES: Only one applicable binding exists, service plan hint \"application\" is not used" }
   2019-01-31T09:49:41.02+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "written_at":"2019-01-31T04:19:41.026Z","written_ts":3583843112511705,"component_id":"ae30fb63-3ddc-42e4-95c9-c190e7c5950e","component_name":"address-manager","DCComponent":"","HOST":"0ca2bbc0-3f71-4dfd-5e4e-8577","organization_name":"-","component_type":"application","space_name":"dev","SERVER":"main","component_instance":"0","organization_id":"-","correlation_id":"-","CSNComponent":"","space_id":"71c96992-bd88-41e6-ac83-bdcc94e38fc6","Application":"address-manager","container_id":"10.0.137.101","type":"log","logger":"com.sap.xs2.security.commons.SAPVcapServicesParser","thread":"http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-10","level":"INFO","categories":[],"msg":"VCAP_SERVICES: Only one applicable binding exists, service plan hint \"application\" is not used" }
   2019-01-31T09:49:41.02+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "written_at":"2019-01-31T04:19:41.026Z","written_ts":3583843112682598,"component_id":"ae30fb63-3ddc-42e4-95c9-c190e7c5950e","component_name":"address-manager","DCComponent":"","HOST":"0ca2bbc0-3f71-4dfd-5e4e-8577","organization_name":"-","component_type":"application","space_name":"dev","SERVER":"main","component_instance":"0","organization_id":"-","correlation_id":"-","CSNComponent":"","space_id":"71c96992-bd88-41e6-ac83-bdcc94e38fc6","Application":"address-manager","container_id":"10.0.137.101","type":"log","logger":"com.sap.xs2.security.commons.SAPPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer","thread":"http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-10","level":"INFO","categories":[],"msg":"Got from VCAP_SERVICES: verificationkey=-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----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-----END PUBLIC KEY-----" }
   2019-01-31T09:49:41.02+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT audit/security-events: {"uuid":"f9e8cee3-accc-4ea0-b1a8-8eb0332610c3","user":"armoghan.abbas@gmail.com","time":"2019-01-31T04:19:41.029Z","ip":"52.28.241.88","data":"Successful log on for 'armoghan.abbas@gmail.com' from 52.28.241.88.","tenant":"9f0f4bb3-bb5f-4745-b992-7d41c3100573"}
   2019-01-31T09:49:41.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "written_at":"2019-01-31T04:19:41.030Z","written_ts":3583843117462454,"component_id":"ae30fb63-3ddc-42e4-95c9-c190e7c5950e","component_name":"address-manager","DCComponent":"","HOST":"0ca2bbc0-3f71-4dfd-5e4e-8577","organization_name":"-","component_type":"application","space_name":"dev","SERVER":"main","component_instance":"0","organization_id":"-","correlation_id":"-","CSNComponent":"","space_id":"71c96992-bd88-41e6-ac83-bdcc94e38fc6","Application":"address-manager","container_id":"10.0.137.101","type":"log","logger":"com.sap.xs.security.container.XSSecurityAuthenticator","thread":"http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-10","level":"WARN","categories":[],"msg":"AuditLog service binding is not available. The message will be written in console output.","stacktrace":["com.sap.xs.audit.api.exception.AuditLogNotAvailableException: Cannot send audit log message to the backend. Missing audit log service credentials parameters or binding to an auditlog service instance.","\tat com.sap.xs.audit.client.impl.ConsoleCommunicator.send(ConsoleCommunicator.java:10)","\tat com.sap.xs.audit.client.impl.AuditLogMessageImpl.log(AuditLogMessageImpl.java:85)","\tat com.sap.xs.security.container.XSSecurityAuthenticator.logSecurityEventAuditMessage(XSSecurityAuthenticator.java:112)","\tat com.sap.xs.security.container.XSSecurityAuthenticator.logSuccessfulLogonAuditMessage(XSSecurityAuthenticator.java:97)","\tat com.sap.xs.security.container.XSSecurityAuthenticator.authenticate(XSSecurityAuthenticator.java:45)","\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:566)","\tat com.sap.xs.security.container.XSSecurityAuthenticator.invoke(XSSecurityAuthenticator.java:131)","\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)","\tat com.sap.xs.java.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:66)","\tat ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve.invoke(LogbackValve.java:191)","\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)","\tat com.sap.xs.security.UserInfoValve.invoke(UserInfoValve.java:19)","\tat com.sap.xs.statistics.tomcat.valve.RequestTracingValve.invoke(RequestTracingValve.java:43)","\tat com.sap.xs.logging.catalina.RuntimeInfoValve.invoke(RuntimeInfoValve.java:40)","\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:695)","\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)","\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1137)","\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)","\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)","\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)","\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)","\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)","\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836)"] }
   2019-01-31T09:49:41.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "written_at":"2019-01-31T04:19:41.034Z","written_ts":3583843120774921,"component_id":"ae30fb63-3ddc-42e4-95c9-c190e7c5950e","component_name":"address-manager","DCComponent":"","HOST":"0ca2bbc0-3f71-4dfd-5e4e-8577","organization_name":"-","component_type":"application","space_name":"dev","SERVER":"main","component_instance":"0","organization_id":"-","correlation_id":"-","CSNComponent":"","space_id":"71c96992-bd88-41e6-ac83-bdcc94e38fc6","Application":"address-manager","container_id":"10.0.137.101","type":"log","logger":"com.sap.cloud.s4hana.examples.addressmgr.BusinessPartnerServlet","thread":"http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-10","level":"INFO","categories":[],"msg":"Retrieving all business partners" }
   2019-01-31T09:49:41.38+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "written_at":"2019-01-31T04:19:41.383Z","written_ts":3583843469583997,"component_id":"ae30fb63-3ddc-42e4-95c9-c190e7c5950e","component_name":"address-manager","DCComponent":"","HOST":"0ca2bbc0-3f71-4dfd-5e4e-8577","organization_name":"-","component_type":"application","space_name":"dev","SERVER":"main","component_instance":"0","organization_id":"-","correlation_id":"-","CSNComponent":"","space_id":"71c96992-bd88-41e6-ac83-bdcc94e38fc6","Application":"address-manager","container_id":"10.0.137.101","type":"log","logger":"com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.connectivity.ErpConfigContext","thread":"http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-10","level":"INFO","categories":[],"msg":"Falling back to locale \"en_US\". To specify the locale, set the property on destination \"ErpQueryEndpoint\" or provide the locale as explicit argument. (END OF LOG ENTRY)" }
   2019-01-31T09:49:41.38+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "written_at":"2019-01-31T04:19:41.384Z","written_ts":3583843471009201,"component_id":"ae30fb63-3ddc-42e4-95c9-c190e7c5950e","component_name":"address-manager","DCComponent":"","HOST":"0ca2bbc0-3f71-4dfd-5e4e-8577","organization_name":"-","component_type":"application","space_name":"dev","SERVER":"main","component_instance":"0","organization_id":"-","correlation_id":"-","CSNComponent":"","space_id":"71c96992-bd88-41e6-ac83-bdcc94e38fc6","Application":"address-manager","container_id":"10.0.137.101","type":"log","logger":"com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.connectivity.ErpConfigContext","thread":"hystrix-com.sap.cloud.s4hana.examples.addressmgr.commands.GetAllProductsCommand#t=#u=-6","level":"INFO","categories":[],"msg":"Falling back to locale \"en_US\". To specify the locale, set the property on destination \"ErpQueryEndpoint\" or provide the locale as explicit argument. (END OF LOG ENTRY)" }
   2019-01-31T09:49:41.38+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "written_at":"2019-01-31T04:19:41.386Z","written_ts":3583843472964643,"component_id":"ae30fb63-3ddc-42e4-95c9-c190e7c5950e","component_name":"address-manager","DCComponent":"","HOST":"0ca2bbc0-3f71-4dfd-5e4e-8577","organization_name":"-","component_type":"application","space_name":"dev","SERVER":"main","component_instance":"0","organization_id":"-","correlation_id":"-","CSNComponent":"","space_id":"71c96992-bd88-41e6-ac83-bdcc94e38fc6","Application":"address-manager","container_id":"10.0.137.101","type":"log","logger":"com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery","thread":"hystrix-com.sap.cloud.s4hana.examples.addressmgr.commands.GetAllProductsCommand#t=#u=-6","level":"ERROR","categories":[],"msg":"Successfully connected to destination service." }
   2019-01-31T09:49:41.64+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "written_at":"2019-01-31T04:19:41.639Z","written_ts":3583843726319402,"component_id":"ae30fb63-3ddc-42e4-95c9-c190e7c5950e","component_name":"address-manager","DCComponent":"","HOST":"0ca2bbc0-3f71-4dfd-5e4e-8577","organization_name":"-","component_type":"application","space_name":"dev","SERVER":"main","component_instance":"0","organization_id":"-","correlation_id":"-","CSNComponent":"","space_id":"71c96992-bd88-41e6-ac83-bdcc94e38fc6","Application":"address-manager","container_id":"10.0.137.101","type":"log","logger":"com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.cache.metadata.GuavaMetadataCache","thread":"hystrix-com.sap.cloud.s4hana.examples.addressmgr.commands.GetAllProductsCommand#t=#u=-6","level":"ERROR","categories":[],"msg":"Error occurred during populating metadata : com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.helper.ODataVdmErrorResultHandler$ErpODataException: " }
   2019-01-31T09:49:41.64+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "written_at":"2019-01-31T04:19:41.640Z","written_ts":3583843726825327,"component_id":"ae30fb63-3ddc-42e4-95c9-c190e7c5950e","component_name":"address-manager","DCComponent":"","HOST":"0ca2bbc0-3f71-4dfd-5e4e-8577","organization_name":"-","component_type":"application","space_name":"dev","SERVER":"main","component_instance":"0","organization_id":"-","correlation_id":"-","CSNComponent":"","space_id":"71c96992-bd88-41e6-ac83-bdcc94e38fc6","Application":"address-manager","container_id":"10.0.137.101","type":"log","logger":"com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery","thread":"hystrix-com.sap.cloud.s4hana.examples.addressmgr.commands.GetAllProductsCommand#t=#u=-6","level":"ERROR","categories":[],"msg":"Successfully connected to destination service." }
   2019-01-31T09:49:41.75+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "written_at":"2019-01-31T04:19:41.751Z","written_ts":3583843838110377,"component_id":"ae30fb63-3ddc-42e4-95c9-c190e7c5950e","component_name":"address-manager","DCComponent":"","HOST":"0ca2bbc0-3f71-4dfd-5e4e-8577","organization_name":"-","component_type":"application","space_name":"dev","SERVER":"main","component_instance":"0","organization_id":"-","correlation_id":"-","CSNComponent":"","space_id":"71c96992-bd88-41e6-ac83-bdcc94e38fc6","Application":"address-manager","container_id":"10.0.137.101","type":"log","logger":"com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.cache.metadata.GuavaMetadataCache","thread":"hystrix-com.sap.cloud.s4hana.examples.addressmgr.commands.GetAllProductsCommand#t=#u=-6","level":"ERROR","categories":[],"msg":"Error occurred during populating metadata : com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.helper.ODataVdmErrorResultHandler$ErpODataException: " }
   2019-01-31T09:49:41.75+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "written_at":"2019-01-31T04:19:41.752Z","written_ts":3583843838680972,"component_id":"ae30fb63-3ddc-42e4-95c9-c190e7c5950e","component_name":"address-manager","DCComponent":"","HOST":"0ca2bbc0-3f71-4dfd-5e4e-8577","organization_name":"-","component_type":"application","space_name":"dev","SERVER":"main","component_instance":"0","organization_id":"-","correlation_id":"-","CSNComponent":"","space_id":"71c96992-bd88-41e6-ac83-bdcc94e38fc6","Application":"address-manager","container_id":"10.0.137.101","type":"log","logger":"com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery","thread":"hystrix-com.sap.cloud.s4hana.examples.addressmgr.commands.GetAllProductsCommand#t=#u=-6","level":"ERROR","categories":[],"msg":"Successfully connected to destination service." }
   2019-01-31T09:49:41.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "written_at":"2019-01-31T04:19:41.864Z","written_ts":3583843950626395,"component_id":"ae30fb63-3ddc-42e4-95c9-c190e7c5950e","component_name":"address-manager","DCComponent":"","HOST":"0ca2bbc0-3f71-4dfd-5e4e-8577","organization_name":"-","component_type":"application","space_name":"dev","SERVER":"main","component_instance":"0","organization_id":"-","correlation_id":"-","CSNComponent":"","space_id":"71c96992-bd88-41e6-ac83-bdcc94e38fc6","Application":"address-manager","container_id":"10.0.137.101","type":"log","logger":"com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.cache.metadata.GuavaMetadataCache","thread":"hystrix-com.sap.cloud.s4hana.examples.addressmgr.commands.GetAllProductsCommand#t=#u=-6","level":"ERROR","categories":[],"msg":"Error occurred during populating metadata : com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.helper.ODataVdmErrorResultHandler$ErpODataException: " }
   2019-01-31T09:49:41.86+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "written_at":"2019-01-31T04:19:41.864Z","written_ts":3583843950942012,"component_id":"ae30fb63-3ddc-42e4-95c9-c190e7c5950e","component_name":"address-manager","DCComponent":"","HOST":"0ca2bbc0-3f71-4dfd-5e4e-8577","organization_name":"-","component_type":"application","space_name":"dev","SERVER":"main","component_instance":"0","organization_id":"-","correlation_id":"-","CSNComponent":"","space_id":"71c96992-bd88-41e6-ac83-bdcc94e38fc6","Application":"address-manager","container_id":"10.0.137.101","type":"log","logger":"com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery","thread":"hystrix-com.sap.cloud.s4hana.examples.addressmgr.commands.GetAllProductsCommand#t=#u=-6","level":"ERROR","categories":[],"msg":"Successfully connected to destination service." }
   2019-01-31T09:49:41.97+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "written_at":"2019-01-31T04:19:41.977Z","written_ts":3583844063669784,"component_id":"ae30fb63-3ddc-42e4-95c9-c190e7c5950e","component_name":"address-manager","DCComponent":"","HOST":"0ca2bbc0-3f71-4dfd-5e4e-8577","organization_name":"-","component_type":"application","space_name":"dev","SERVER":"main","component_instance":"0","organization_id":"-","correlation_id":"-","CSNComponent":"","space_id":"71c96992-bd88-41e6-ac83-bdcc94e38fc6","Application":"address-manager","container_id":"10.0.137.101","type":"log","logger":"com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.cache.metadata.GuavaMetadataCache","thread":"hystrix-com.sap.cloud.s4hana.examples.addressmgr.commands.GetAllProductsCommand#t=#u=-6","level":"ERROR","categories":[],"msg":"Error occurred during populating metadata : com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.helper.ODataVdmErrorResultHandler$ErpODataException: " }
   2019-01-31T09:49:41.98+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "written_at":"2019-01-31T04:19:41.980Z","written_ts":3583844066956104,"component_id":"ae30fb63-3ddc-42e4-95c9-c190e7c5950e","component_name":"address-manager","DCComponent":"","HOST":"0ca2bbc0-3f71-4dfd-5e4e-8577","organization_name":"-","component_type":"application","space_name":"dev","SERVER":"main","component_instance":"0","organization_id":"-","correlation_id":"-","CSNComponent":"","space_id":"71c96992-bd88-41e6-ac83-bdcc94e38fc6","Application":"address-manager","container_id":"10.0.137.101","type":"log","logger":"com.sap.cloud.s4hana.examples.addressmgr.commands.GetAllProductsCommand","thread":"hystrix-com.sap.cloud.s4hana.examples.addressmgr.commands.GetAllProductsCommand#t=#u=-6","level":"WARN","categories":[],"msg":"Fallback called because of exception:","stacktrace":["java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataException: Failed to execute OData Metadata request.","\tat com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:526)","\tat com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:487)","\tat com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:83)","\tat com.google.common.util.concurrent.Uninterruptibles.getUninterruptibly(Uninterruptibles.java:196)","\tat com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.getAndRecordStats(LocalCache.java:2311)","\tat com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2277)","\tat com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154)","\tat com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044)","\tat com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3951)","\tat com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4870)","\tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.frameworks.hystrix.CachingCommand.run(CachingCommand.java:178)","\tat com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:302)","\tat com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:298)","\tat rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46)","\tat rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)","\tat rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)","\tat rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)","\tat rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)","\tat rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)","\tat rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)","\tat rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)","\tat rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256)","\tat rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51)","\tat rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)","\tat rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256)","\tat rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)","\tat rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)","\tat rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)","\tat rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)","\tat rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256)","\tat rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:100)","\tat com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:56)","\tat com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:47)","\tat com.sap.xs.threadlocal.hystrix.ThreadLocalCallable.call(ThreadLocalCallable.java:29)","\tat com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:69)","\tat rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)","\tat java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)","\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)","\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)","\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)","\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836)","Caused by: com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataException: Failed to execute OData Metadata request.","\tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.loadEntriesFromDestination(ODataQuery.java:215)","\tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.internalExecute(ODataQuery.java:167)","\tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.execute(ODataQuery.java:105)","\tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.execute(ODataQuery.java:150)","\tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.execute(ODataQuery.java:136)","\tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.helper.FluentHelperRead.execute(FluentHelperRead.java:197)","\tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.helper.FluentHelperRead.execute(FluentHelperRead.java:23)","\tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.helper.FluentHelperBasic.execute(FluentHelperBasic.java:85)","\tat com.sap.cloud.s4hana.examples.addressmgr.commands.GetAllProductsCommand.runCacheable(GetAllProductsCommand.java:53)","\tat com.sap.cloud.s4hana.examples.addressmgr.commands.GetAllProductsCommand.runCacheable(GetAllProductsCommand.java:19)","\tat com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4875)","\tat com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3527)","\tat com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2276)","\t... 35 more","Caused by: com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.helper.ODataVdmErrorResultHandler$ErpODataException: ","\tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.helper.ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.createException(ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.java:105)","\tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.helper.ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.createError(ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.java:86)","\tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.helper.ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.createError(ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.java:31)","\tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.internal.ODataConnectivityUtil.checkHttpStatus(ODataConnectivityUtil.java:185)","\tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.cache.metadata.GuavaMetadataCache.getEdm(GuavaMetadataCache.java:131)","\tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.cache.metadata.GuavaMetadataCache.getEdm(GuavaMetadataCache.java:110)","\tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.loadMetadata(ODataQuery.java:250)","\tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.loadEntriesFromDestination(ODataQuery.java:213)","\t... 47 more"] }
   2019-01-31T09:49:41.98+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "written_at":"2019-01-31T04:19:41.981Z","written_ts":3583844067895750,"component_id":"ae30fb63-3ddc-42e4-95c9-c190e7c5950e","component_name":"address-manager","DCComponent":"","HOST":"0ca2bbc0-3f71-4dfd-5e4e-8577","organization_name":"-","component_type":"application","space_name":"dev","SERVER":"main","component_instance":"0","organization_id":"-","correlation_id":"-","CSNComponent":"","space_id":"71c96992-bd88-41e6-ac83-bdcc94e38fc6","Application":"address-manager","container_id":"10.0.137.101","type":"log","logger":"com.sap.cloud.s4hana.examples.addressmgr.BusinessPartnerServlet","thread":"http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-10","level":"INFO","categories":[],"msg":"Armoghan says - []" }
   address-manager-grumpy-otter.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com - [2019-01-31T04:19:41.027+0000] "GET /api/business-partners HTTP/1.1" 200 0 2 "https://approuter-p1942271708trial.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/address-manager/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36" "-" "10.0.137.101:61002" x_forwarded_for:"-" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"4b3e148c-ac4a-444f-5676-00f83c7fda10" response_time:0.963585441 app_id:"ae30fb63-3ddc-42e4-95c9-c190e7c5950e" app_index:"0" x_correlationid:"c3b465c1-cdad-4fe4-7033-9c9b3d8b7971" x_b3_traceid:"ee848c54fc661573" x_b3_spanid:"ee848c54fc661573" x_b3_parentspanid:"-"

[image: subaccount in cloud connector]

[image: Destination in cloud foundary]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you post the complete log output? It seems like the full stack trace may not be contained.

Comment: Yes, this is what I got from logs section of my application in cloud foundry, can you tell me more about what you are looking for? I will try to provide data accordingly

Comment: Did you also whitelist the consumed (Product Master) service (see the last screenshot in the [blog post](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/07/09/how-to-use-the-sap-cloud-platform-connectivity-and-the-cloud-connector-in-the-cloud-foundry-environment-part-1/))? Also, do you see any error messages in the Audit Log of the SAP Cloud Connector?

Comment: I can see audit logs in my application's logs (updating in post), but there are no such logs in my cloud connector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had not put any value in 'Location' field of my destination, I am able to fetch values from a standard OData service now.

Answer (score 4):

When connecting against an On-Premise system, you need to have a connectivity service instance bound to your application, in addition to xs-uaa and destination service instances. Also, make sure that you have configured the Cloud Connector correctly.
[The following deep dive](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/01/19/deep-dive-7-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-s4hana-connectivity-made-simple/) describes the required prerequisites to connect to S/4HANA OP from SAP Cloud Platform Cloud Foundry (see the abstract Running Business Partner Calls Against S/4HANA On-Premise)

Comment: Hello K3na, thanks for responding. I did follow these steps. I am adding application logs in my post.